# Regexp with letters and -

Tags: html, regex

I need a regexp with letters and - to use as pattern validate of an input type text,
for example:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name form" pattern="[A-Za-z-]" required="required">
```

But it still validate also other characters when i fill and sumbit form.

Comment: Are you sure it works at all? Try `pattern="[A-Za-z-]+"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern (`[A-Za-z\-]+`) to check for the whole input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name form" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" required="required">
```

Comment: You do not need `^` and `$`, `pattern="[A-Za-z-]+"`  is enough.